# How to use the class or write in winform if class parameter is array

Tags: c#, class

this is code of the class, i want to pass the columns, tables and condition to reuse the class.

```
 public class Dbclass
{
somecodes.......


public DataSet SelectQuery(string[] columns,string tables,string condition)
{
    string col = string.Join(",", columns);
    string tbl = string.Join(",", tables);
    string selectSQL = "SELECT " + col + " FROM " + tbl + cond;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, this.DBcon);
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet retrnds = new DataSet();
}
}
```

what i want to,codes in winform:

```
Dbclass dbclass = new DbClass();
dbclass.SelectQuery({"FirstName","LastName"},"Employee","Where EmployeeID=1");
```

Comment: I believe you should explore existing ORM frameworks before trying to come up with your own.

Comment: I mean to start with, your method should be **inside** your class.

Comment: please start learning  [Entity Framework (code-first)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this two strings ( string col,string tbl ) globally in your form so you can reuse it whenever required, Or Apply MVP Design pattern where you can achieve Reusability